# ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator completing without error, but no change to Feature?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I'm attempting a research project in which I am seeking to categorize a municipality's Property Use Codes as Generalized Land Uses.  For example, "AGRII - Developed Farmland" and "INDGR - Grain Elevator" are both "Agricultural" land uses.  I have created a new field "Land Use Category" and used the following code:

PLY_AssessmentParcels_LandUseCategory = `MyFunction(!Assessment_Parcels_CSV_csv_Property_Use_Code!)`
_

```
def MyFunction(s):
   if ("AGRII" or "INDGR") in s:
      return "Agricultural"
   elif ("VRES2" or "VRES1" or "VINDU" or "VCOMM" or "VAPRK" or "VAGRI" or "CNVAC") in s:
      return "Vacant"
   elif ("STATR" or "SKYWK" or "RAILR" or "ARPRT" or "CMPST" or "CMPSP") in s:
      return "Transportation"
   elif ("RESTR" or "RESSU" or "RESSS" or "RESSD" or "RESRM" or "RESRH" or "RESOT" or "RESMU" or "RESMH" or "RESMC" or "RESMB" or "RESGC" or "RESAP" or "RESDU" or "RESAM" or "CNAPT" or "CNCMP" or "CNDRH" or "CNRES") in s:
      return "Residential"
   elif ("CMCMU" or "CMFBK" or "CMHBH" or "CMHHO" or "CMHMO" or "CMMRH" or "CMOFF" or "CMOGV" or "CMOMC" or "CMRCS" or "CMRCV" or "CMRNS" or "CMRRE" or "CMRRS" or "CMRSM" or "SMRST" or "CMRWC" or "CMVCD" or "CMVSR") in s:
      return "Commercial"
   elif ("CNCOM" or "REFRL" or "CMSTP") in s:
      return "Other"
   elif ("PIRST" or "PIRRT" or "PIRRI" or "PIRPO" or "PIRPK" or "PIRMU" or "PIRGC" or "PIRCC" or "PIRBA" or "PIRAR" or "PIEBM" or "PIECS" or "PIETC") in s:
      return "Recreational"
   elif ("CNIND" or "HYDSS" or "INMHM" or "INMLM" or "INMMI" or "INMMU" or "INWSC" or "INWWH" or "MTSSS" or "TRAPI") in s:
      return "Industrial"
   elif ("PIEMA" or "PIICH" or "PIIDC" or "PIIGC" or "PIIHO" or "PIIMB" or "PIINH" or "PIIPF" or "PIIRE" or "PIISC" or "PIIUC" or "PIMCE" or "PIMFH" or "PIMLI") in s:
      return "Institutional"
   else:
      return
```

When I run the above code, I often received an error stating "Cannot acquire lock".  After restarting ArcGIS Pro, I can usually get one good run out in which the process completes successfully in about 40 seconds.  The problem is that nothing has changed in my attribute table.  Please note, I'm dealing with about 212,000 records.  The file is stored in a .gdb and I have re-created the feature class in the .gdb with the same issues.  System specs are very reasonable (i7 7800k, 32gb ram, GTX 1080i, etc.)

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of attribute table]

Comment: Can you try on a few records? I was having a similar problem last week. I verified with a small case, a few records and one statement, then added the rest. Maybe try selecting a few rows of "AGRII" and run with if ("AGRII") in s: return "Agricultural". See if that gives you some success.

Comment: Can be as simple as setting environment extent.

Comment: Are you sure the field name is !Assessment_Parcels_CSV_csv_Property_Use_Code!, and not the field alias? You should return something at the last else, like "ERROR" and see if fields are filled with this. Otherwise the function will return a None, which might not work if field is not nullable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. @BERA thanks for the suggestion - it is filling everything in as 'Error'.  Definitely something wrong with my code.

Comment: Well then it is doing something which is better than nothing. Could you add a screenshot showing the attribute table? Try adding `s = s.strip()` before the if lines. It will strip whitespaces. You know that python is case sensitive right? So AAA is not the same as aaa

Comment: Thanks @BERA.  Screenshot added.  s.strip() didn't work.  As you can see as well, the case should match.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I switched to the following any() command:

```
def MyFunction(s):
    if any(x in s for x in ["AGRII", "INDGR"]):
        return "Agricultural"

...

else:
    return "Error"
```

My hunch is that I am trying to check if a whole *Tuple* (such as "('AGRII' or 'INDGR')" is contained within a *string* (which will always return false). Thanks for the help!